# Output Thumbs interval in % ElasticTranscoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using the ElasticTranscoder from Amazon and my app it's almost finished now.
The problem I have is as follow:

Users can upload some video's and I want from every video 5 thumbnails. 
Now i want the preset interval in procents, so i have 5 different thumbnails between the whole video.

Does someone here know, if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lame solution, it works but maybe there are resolutions thats better then myn.

Now i list all objects in a bucket/ folder, takes 5 files, removes the others and rename's te files that's remain.